# how to get the filed mapName 's value on a form.. uding django

Tags: django, forms

my form is

```
class MapForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Map
        fields = ('mapName', 'kmlStr')
```

and  the view is :

```
map_form = MapForm(request.POST or None)
if map_form.is_valid():
    map = map_form.save(commit=False)
    map.mapName=map_form.mapName#is this code right ?
```

how to get the mapName 's value , us 'map_form.mapName' ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite, you want to access the form fields through [cleaned_data](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form)

> Processing the data from a form
>
> Once is_valid() returns True, you can
>   process the form submission safe in
>   the knowledge that it conforms to the
>   validation rules defined by your form.
>   While you could access request.POST
>   directly at this point, it is better
>   to access form.cleaned_data. This data
>   has not only been validated but will
>   also be converted in to the relevant
>   Python types for you. In the above
>   example, cc_myself will be a boolean
>   value. Likewise, fields such as
>   IntegerField and FloatField convert
>   values to a Python int and float
>   respectively.

```
map.mapName = map_form.cleaned_data['mapName']
```

However, you're already using model forms, so you can save the form to return an object.

```
map_form = MapForm(request.POST or None)
if map_form.is_valid():
    map = map_form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's modelform, fields mapName and kmlStr are alredy stored in Map object at

```
map = map_form.save(commit=False)
```

to get value from form you need to do `form.cleaned_data['mapName']`